# Averaging along DataFrame columns with some missing rows

Tags: python, pandas

I have a DataFrame object with several columns like that:

```
+--------+---------------------+-------+-------+-------+
|        |        Date         | temp1 | temp2 | temp3 |
+--------+---------------------+-------+-------+-------+
|  17687 | 2013-10-21 00:04:47 | 14.50 | 13.55 | 43.06 |
|  48117 | 2013-10-21 00:18:07 | 14.64 | 13.42 | 37.48 |
|  76509 | 2013-10-21 00:33:51 | 14.32 | 13.55 | 27.26 |
| 102769 | 2013-10-21 00:48:24 | 14.38 | 13.30 | 37.10 |
| 133862 | 2013-10-21 01:04:36 | 14.77 | 13.11 | 28.25 |
| 162882 | 2013-10-21 01:18:14 | 14.50 | 13.98 | 39.71 |
| 191902 | 2013-10-21 01:34:11 | 14.39 | 13.08 | 28.69 |
| 220922 | 2013-10-21 01:48:38 | 14.31 | 13.00 | 43.56 |
| 249942 | 2013-10-21 02:04:26 | 14.10 | 13.94 | 39.79 |
| 278962 | 2013-10-21 02:18:13 | 14.01 | 13.55 | 23.46 |
| 307982 | 2013-10-21 02:34:04 | 14.00 | 13.21 | 44.94 |
| 337002 | 2013-10-21 02:48:27 | 14.81 | 13.38 | 29.44 |
+--------+---------------------+-------+-------+-------+
...
+--------+---------------------+-------+-------+-------+
|  15531 | 2013-10-22 00:05:20 | 14.84 | 13.07 | 30.25 |
|  44149 | 2013-10-22 00:18:11 | 14.35 | 13.22 | 51.02 |
| 102685 | 2013-10-22 00:49:34 | 14.46 | 13.98 | 24.17 |
| 127960 | 2013-10-22 01:04:02 | 14.07 | 13.49 | 30.74 |
| 186892 | 2013-10-22 01:34:14 | 14.75 | 13.01 | 45.77 |
| 214754 | 2013-10-22 01:48:17 | 14.35 | 13.03 | 40.75 |
| 240236 | 2013-10-22 02:02:39 | 14.31 | 13.28 | 34.88 |
| 507942 | 2013-10-21 02:34:04 | 14.87 | 13.62 | 50.16 |
| 111987 | 2013-10-21 02:48:27 | 14.74 | 13.63 | 51.36 |
+--------+---------------------+-------+-------+-------+
```

The problem is to find average values of temp1, temp2 and temp3 for a period of time (say, 2 days) over the same intervals (for that example - 15 minutes).
There are two issues: (1) some rows were missed; (2) temperatures were measured in slightly different (+- 3 minutes in whole dataset and 2 minutes in that particular example) time.

As of now, my solution is based on 2 steps. First, find maximum number of intervals along the day (look through all days in base). Create a new DataFrame object with corresponding number of rows. Second, go through dataset and add values to correspond row if current date within 3 minutes.
Unfortunately, it's a bit of slow because of iterative nature. I'm trying to find a way to do it faster.

Any suggestions?

Thanks

P.S. It would be nice to see a result like that (first column is some averaged time):

```
+---------+-------+-------+-------+
|  Time   | temp1 | temp2 | temp3 |
+---------+-------+-------+-------+
| 0:05:00 | 14.67 | 13.31 | 36.66 |
| 0:18:00 | 14.50 | 13.32 | 44.25 |
| 0:34:00 | 14.32 | 13.55 | 27.26 |
| 0:49:00 | 14.42 | 13.64 | 30.64 |
| 1:04:00 | 14.42 | 13.30 | 29.50 |
| 1:18:00 | 14.50 | 13.98 | 39.71 |
| 1:34:00 | 14.57 | 13.05 | 37.23 |
| 1:48:00 | 14.33 | 13.02 | 42.16 |
| 2:03:00 | 14.21 | 13.61 | 37.34 |
| 2:18:00 | 14.01 | 13.55 | 23.46 |
| 2:34:00 | 14.44 | 13.42 | 47.55 |
| 2:48:00 | 14.78 | 13.51 | 40.40 |
+---------+-------+-------+-------+
```

Comment: can you provide desired result for your sample dataset?

Comment: It's not clear where the +/- 3 minutes is coming in. None of the rows in your example are within 3 minutes of each other I think. To answer your question, I'd think that `df.resample('3t', how='mean') would work.  You may want to clarify your question/example.

Comment: +/- 3 minutes came because of the nature of the experiment. In my example here the maximum difference is slightly less than 2 minutes.

Comment: Can't help about reopening the question, but also still uncertain about results logic: if interval is 15 mins, then why your result times contains `5:00`,`18:00` and `34:00` instead of `5:00`, `20:00` and '35:00' or `4:00` and `19:00` and `34:00`?

Comment: For that example it was just averages. In 30 days sample it would be close to your timing (0:05, 0:20, 0:35, 0:50, 1:05, 1:20, 1:35, 1:50, 2:05, 2:20, 2:35, and 2:50).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does following solve your task?

```
import datetime
from collections import defaultdict

def avg(lst):
    return sum(lst)/len(lst)
```

Define some sample data

```
def s2dt(s):
    fmt = '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'
    return datetime.datetime.strptime(s, fmt)

data = [(s2dt('2013-10-21 00:04:47'), 14.50, 13.55, 43.06),
        (s2dt('2013-10-21 00:18:07'), 14.64, 13.42, 37.48),
        (s2dt('2013-10-22 00:05:20'), 14.84, 13.07, 30.25),
        (s2dt('2013-10-22 00:18:11'), 14.35, 13.22, 51.02)]
```

Define a function that will group times by periods

```
def coarse(dt, granularity):
    residue = dt.minute % granularity
    if residue:
        residue = granularity-residue
    dt = dt + datetime.timedelta(minutes=residue, seconds=-dt.second,
                    microseconds=-dt.microsecond)
    t = dt.time()
    return t
```

Group data by intervals

```
groupings = defaultdict(list)
for dt, t1, t2, t3 in data:
    groupings[coarse(dt, 15)].append([t1, t2, t3])
```

Calculate average

```
averages = dict((k, map(avg, zip(*v))) for k, v in groupings.iteritems())
```

and get

```
>>> for ct, values in sorted(averages.iteritems()):
...   print ct, ', '.join(map(lambda x: '%.2f' % x, values))
00:15:00 14.67, 13.31, 36.66
00:30:00 14.50, 13.32, 44.25
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Is there a simple way to calculate actual average or median time instead of strictly granular? E.g., average between 00:04:45 and 00:05:25 would be 00:05:05

Comment: You can convert times to seconds, evaluate avg of result the same way as for features t1, t2, t3; then convert back to time object if needed. don't know whether there are standart funcs for those operations, but it won't be hard either way. if you'll be troubled on that path, do not hesitate to open new question.